# HTML Page not responsive on phone but ok in browser when browser resized

Tags: html, responsive

Trying to make the page below resize properly on a phone. It works ok in a laptop browser when I resize the browser. It just looks smaller on a phone. Am pretty new to this and would appreciate if anyone could show me where I've gone wrong.

Here's the `html` and its style.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=password],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-10 {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of                    other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container .col-10,
  .col-25,
  .col-75,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="login-content">
      <form action="input.php" class="form-login" method="POST">
        <h2 class="title">FROG Login to input your times for the hole</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-25">
            <h5>Username</h5>
            <input type="text" id="fusername" name="fusername">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-25">
            <h5>Password</h5>
            <input type="password" id="fpassword" name="fpassword">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-10">
            <label for="hole">Hole</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <select id="fhole" name="fhole">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login">
        <br><br><br>
        <p>Forgot Username/Password? Please contact JH via IG</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the issue? Take a look at [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)